# Table not getting populated in Athena

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to create a table in Athena from the JSON files that are present in an S3 bucket.
Following is the query -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `sample_tablename` (
`sample_column1` string,
`sample_column2` integer
)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
`sample_column3` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
's3://bukcet_name/folder_name'
TBLPROPERTIES (
'classification'='json')
```

My JSON file looks like -

```
[{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"},{"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}]
```

The table is getting formed with the partition but the table is empty. There is no error message. What possibly is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the expected format is separate rows of JSON records, like this:

```json
{"sample_column1": "abcd","sample_column2": "efgh"}
{"sample_column1": "ijkl","sample_column2": "mnop"}
```

See: [AWS Athena with simple JSON data – PRESTOCOMPUTE](https://prestocompute.wordpress.com/2017/01/23/aws-athena-with-simple-json-data/)

Comment: Tried this. Table is still empty.

Comment: I suggest you run the sample code in that article so that you can reproduce their query output, then replace the sample data with your own data. That should help identify what is causing the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run [MSCK REPAIR TABLE](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/msck-repair-table.html) on partitioned tables:

> The MSCK REPAIR TABLE command scans a file system such as Amazon S3 for Hive compatible partitions that were added to or removed from the file system after the table was created. The command updates the metadata in the catalog regarding the partitions and the data associated with them.

This is also mentioned in the [CREATE TABLE documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/create-table.html)

> After you create a table with partitions, run a subsequent query that consists of the MSCK REPAIR TABLE clause to refresh partition metadata, for example, MSCK REPAIR TABLE cloudfront_logs;. For partitions that are not Hive compatible, use ALTER TABLE ADD PARTITION to load the partitions so that you can query the data.

Afterwards you'll most likely run into the format issue that John is referring to.